# Multiplying the same column number for two different data frames single expression

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

Is there a way to multiple the 1st column from one df to the 1st column in a second df, then the 2nd column from one df to the 2nd column in a second df, so on so forth?

I can do it in a for loop, but was wondering if there was a way to do it in a single expression..

Thank you!

This is what I have so far that isn't working, just get nan's

```
bfAvg = (tankbase.iloc[:,:4].multiply(tankwater.iloc[:,:4],axis=0))
```

Comment: `tankbase * tankwater`?

Comment: Column labels have to do the same